# Kendo grid initializing number cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

By default, all fields in datasource marked as number will have their cells filled with an initial value of 0. I'd like to have the cells empty when the grid is created without turning the field into string.

The below row is added by calling grid.addRow();

[image]

```
$("#SALE_01_DIV_GRID")
                .kendoGrid(
                    {
                        ...
                        dataSource : {
                            schema : {
                                data: "Data",
                                total: "Total",
                                model: {
                                    fields : {
                                        SEQ : { type : "string", editable : false},
                                        SAP_CD : {  type : "string" },
                                        OLD_CD : {  type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        INV_NAME : {    type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        LINE_NAME : {   type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        COLOR : {   type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        DESCNT : {  type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        COMMISSION : {  type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        SAVE_YN : { type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        ERR_MSG : { type : "string", editable : false   },
                                        PAN_QTY : { type : "number" },
                                        SDANGA : { type : "number", editable : false },
                                        PANAMT : { type : "number", editable : false },
                                        JDANGA : { type : "number", editable : false },
                                        JAMT : { type : "number", editable : false },
                                        CURRENT_STOCK : { type : "number", editable : false },
                                        SUPPLY_DANGA : { type : "number", editable : false },
                                        SUPPLY_AMT : { type : "number", editable : false }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
```

Documentation yielded no result. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model definition include [`defaultValue`](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/model#methods-Model.define). Example:

SDANGA : { type : "number", defaultValue: "" },